# Were there any artists that worked on early One Piece episodes that also worked on Seven Deadly Sins?

Tags: one-piece, seven-deadly-sins

I’m watching One Piece from the beginning and I’m currently in the Arlong Park arc. Near the end of episode 31, Hatchan has cooked an entire pig for Momoo and it has a strong resemblance to Hawk from The Seven Deadly Sins:

[image]

Now, I want to believe this is a coincidence, but part of me wants to know that this artist had a very successful career and worked on both anime. Unfortunately, my efforts to find the list of artists that worked on both shows have proven to be fruitless ventures.

---

Were there any artists that worked on early One Piece episodes that also worked on Seven Deadly Sins, or is this pure coincidence?

Answer (score 4):

To me, the pig in that scene in One Piece is a pretty generic pig. You can compare with these images of pigs from mangas: [pig characters](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/pigs)

Also, the *Seven Deadly Sins* manga was released from 2012 to 2020, while the Arlong Park arc in One Piece was released in 1999 (2000 for the animation). Eiichiro Oda drew that scene without knowing *Seven Deadly Sins*, and it is hard to imagine that the author of *Seven Deadly Sins* took inspiration from such a trivial scene.

Comment: This would be the best answer, as it rules out the possibility based on timeline. I guess there can be no tribute to the characters of the future if they have not been created yet.

Answer (score 2):

I see https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Hawk?file=Hawk+Anime+Season+3+Design.png and image share are somewhat different.

While both are pigs, I see Hawk has small nails/hoofs & long ears. There are more differences but I believe you got a bit mixed up - just like me when I read this question :)

Answer (score -1):

Oda often pays tribute to other artists that are relevant at the time of drawing.

Another example of tribute:
[One Piece - Naruto tribute](https://sleepinggeeks.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/one-piece-naruto-tribute.jpg)

But as pointed out, by Taladris, this cannot be the case as the realted OP chapter was created long before SDS.